# What program in windows is equivalent to OS's terminal?

Tags: windows, macos

Switching from programming on Mac to windows, and I need to access github. Don't know where to submit bash commands in order to clone my repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest built-in equivalent is `cmd.exe`. It is, however, not a `bash` shell: the command set is very different.

If you specifically need `bash`, you could install [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/).

Answer (score 8):

I made the switch last year and I actually don't mind using Windows since I found some nice tools.

This is the best terminal I have found used yet: http://bliker.github.io/cmder/

New link: http://cmder.net/

New new link: https://cmder.app/

The great thing is you can use UNIX commands as well. You can even do something such as:
vim run.bat
to edit a batch file.

Comment: Do you know if there is a terminal equivalent already accessible on windows that I just don't know about, or do I have to use an emulator? Thanks!!

Comment: link to cmder is broken...

Comment: @mix3d http://cmder.net

Answer (score 1):

If you're going the command line way for git access, you're probably looking for msys git: https://msysgit.github.io/